# Was ist das Gegenteil von "Nordlicht"?

Tags: single-word-request, idiom

Bewohner von Norddeutschland werden hin und wieder als "Nordlichter" bezeichnet.

Gibt es analog bzw. als Umkehrung dazu eine Bezeichnung für die Süddeutschen?

Comment: Du solltest dazusagen, ob das eine Eigenbezeichnung oder eine Fremdbezeichnung oder beides ist.

Comment: @thei: Was sind denn eine Eigenbezeichnung und/oder Fremdbezeichnung? Die Begriffe sagen mir nichts ...

Comment: Ich würde mal sagen "Eigenbezeichnung" ist etwas, was "Nordlichter" für sich selbst benutzen, "Fremdbezeichnung" etwas, was andere benutzen.  Eine Fremdbezeichnung ist dann gern mal potentiell beleidigend (gemeint).  Kann dann aber auch zur Eigenbezeichnung werden (vgl. "Nigger" im US-Englischen).  Genauso kann eine  Eigenbezeichnung für "Fremde" beleidigend oder herablassend klingen.

Comment: @jae: Als Nordlicht würde ich sagen, dass es beides ist - wir verwenden es für uns selbst, und ich habe es schon oft genug in z.B. Zeitungsartikeln aus Süddeutschland oder ganz Deutschland gelesen. In jedem Fall nicht beleidigend. Da kenne ich andere Bezeichnungen, und zwar sowohl für Nord- als auch für Süddeutschland.

Comment: Ich hatte beleidigend auch nicht auf Nordlicht bezogen, sondern auf (ungenannte) Begriffe.

Comment: @Oregon: hmmm jetzt hat mich doch die Neugierde.  Hast du vielleicht ne URL oder sowas mit ner Liste?  Google ist nicht sehr hilfreich, bzw mein Google-Fu schlecht ;-)  Ich kenne nur (für Nordlichter) "Schlickrutscher" (wohl eher negativ, also ich mag's nicht) und "Muschelschubser" (hoffentlich nicht negativ, ich find das Bild süss :D)

Comment: @jae: Die sind mir beide unbekannt. Nein, eine Liste habe ich nicht. Ich dachte eher an "Fischköppe". "Norditaliener" für Süddeutsche, auf der anderen Seite, ist vielleicht eher scherzhaft als beleidigend gemeint, um zu betonen, wie weit südlich das ist :) "Muschelschubser" erinnert mich an "Saftschubse", hmm. Deine Beispiele konzentrieren sich natürlich irgendwie aufs Watt. Watt gibt's aber wiederum nur an der Nordsee...

Comment: @Oregon: hmm, Fischkopp (oder Fischkopf) hatte ich vergessen.  Norditaliener kannte ich noch nicht :D

Comment: Mir fällt noch "Bergvölker" bzw. "Flachlandbewohner" ein... Verallgemeinerungen sind generell was wunderbares ;-)

Comment: Südlicht........

Comment: @markus Das _IST_ es. Ich Trottel habe immer nur an Süddunkelheit gedacht ...

Comment: Ich denke, dass ist mal wieder ein Fall für die klassischen innerdeutschen Sprachgrenzen - und da der ganze Norden seit einiger Zeit die niederdeutschen Dialekte zugunsten eines einheitlichen Hochdeutsches abgelegt hat, wird er halt als ein "Kulturraum" wahrgenommen... während "Süddeutschland" immer noch aus (sprachlichen) Kleinstaaten besteht und daher keine einheitliche Bezeichnung erlaubt. Oder wer bitte würde Franken und Schwaben in einen Topf werfen wollen? ;)

Comment: @ladybug Na, jeder außer Franken und Schwaben halt ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mir fallen keine Begriffe für Süddeutsche ein, wobei ja auch erstmal definiert werden müsste, was "Norddeutschland" und was "Süddeutschland" ist.  In meinem eigenen Sprachgebrauch, bzw dem Gebrauch den ich so erlebe, ist Süddeutschland Baden-Württemberg und Bayern;  Norddeutschland dagegen vor allem Nordseeküste (Ostsee kam (vor allem oder ausschliesslich?) durch die ehem. DDR hinzu), und küstennahe Gebiete.

In diesem Sinne ist etwas Gemeinsames, bzw gemeinsame Eigenarten/Eigenschaften (auch nur als Klischee) des "Süddeutschen" schwieriger zu finden als bei "Nordlichtern".

Comment: Als Bewohner des Landes zwischen den Meeren muss ich entschieden dagegen protestieren, dass die Ostsee vor allem oder gar ausschließlich durch die ehem. DDR hinzukam - schließlich heißt es ja *up ewig ungedeelt*, und das betrifft folglich beide Küsten von Schleswig-Holstein :) Außerdem gehört der "neue" Teil der Ostseeküste ja nun einmal auch zu Norddeutschland. Wenn man eine Trennlinie suchen will, würde ich sie "irgendwo in der Mitte" ziehen wollen - auch wenn wir hier oben scherzhaft Hamburg das Tor nach Süddeutschland nennen und die Alpenbewohner sicherlich äquivalente Scherze machen.

Comment: Ihre Protestnote wurde zu Kenntnis genommen.  ;-)  Ich hatte das "?" da schon sehr bewusst hingetan. :D  Wobei ich ja (was mir gerade wieder einfiel) mal in meiner Kindheit/Jugend an der Ostsee (aber eben innerhalb BRD) Urlaub machte.  :-P

Comment: Ja, dann war das sogar Schleswig-Holstein, vielleicht hier ganz in der Nähe :) Warum nennt man uns denn so? Weil es im Norden Nordlichter gibt? Hier sind eigentlich eher selten welche zu sehen... Im Grimm wird leider keine Wortherkunft erklärt, vermutlich ist diese Verwendung jüngeren Ursprungs.

Comment: +1 übrigens für den Hinweis, dass es schwieriger ist, für die "Süddeutschen" etwas gemeinsames zu finden. Wobei das vielleicht nur daran liegt, dass es einfach kein passendes Wort gibt, das mit "Süd" beginnt ;)

Comment: @Oregon "Alpenbewohner"? ;-)  Passt aber eben nicht, weil hier nicht alles Gebirge ist (Karlsruhe ist eigentlich ziemlich topeben).

Comment: @jae: Das sind aber sehr weit südlich wohnende Menschen, die ich als Gegenstück zu Schleswig-Holsteinern als Extremfall nennen wollte - Bayern und Baden-Württemberg sind ja schon ziemlich lang :) Wobei, wenn für manch einen Nordlichter immer Küstenbewohner sind, passt Alpenbewohner doch als Gegenstück :D

Comment: @jae: selbst München ist noch flach wie 'ne Flunder!

Comment: @lady stimmt auch wieder...

Comment: Ich markiere mal diese hier als Antwort, hauptsächlich wegen des Hinweises auf gemeinsame Eigenarten/Eigenschaften als Grundlage der Begriffsfindung.

Answer (score 5):

Ich sehe das wie jae, das es auf die Definition von Süddeutsch ankommt.

Man hört aber öfter den Ausdruck "**die Bazis**" für Bayern / Süddeutsche, oder?

Comment: zumindest für die Bayern ist 'Bazi' gebräuchlich

Comment: Bazi ist aber glaube ich ein eher 'innerbayrischer' Ausdruck. Zumindest habe ich das bisher nur von Leuten gehört die auch bayrische Mundart sprachen.

Comment: @takrl: ohne jetzt nachschlagen zu wollen, würde ich dir zustimmen.  Auch der Klang, "Bazi" ist sehr bayrisch (Betonung auf der ersten Silbe, mit langem a.  Hmm, klingt ja fast wie "Nazi" (nur eben kurzes i statt lang wie in Nazi)  Doch mal Tante Google bemühen)

Comment: Also ich komme aus und wohne in Norddeutschland und ich hab das hier schon öfter von Norddeutschen als (oft auch abfällige) Bezeichnung für Bayern gehört ... wenn es sowohl in Bayern als auch in Norddeutschland gebräuchlich ist, passt es ja ideal zu Nordlicht ...

Comment: Hab ich in Sachsen noch nie gehört und da lästern weiß Gott genug über die Bayern... hier in München hab ich den Ausdruck bisher nur für Hunde gehört (so wie "Süßer").

Comment: Ich komme aus Bayern. Für mich ist ein Bazi ein schlauer, gerissener Mensch (oft ein Junge), wobei das Wort meist humorvoll verwendet wird und nicht beleidigt. Das Maskottchen von Bayern München heißt auch Bazi.

Comment: Ja, die Bedeutungen von Bazi sind in Bayern und Norddeutschland komplett unterschiedlich (wenn nicht sogar widersprüchlich) ...

Comment: @jae In Bayern war "Nazi" auch ein Kosename für den Vornamen "Ignaz".

Answer (score 5):

Zwar gibt es den Begriff *[Nordlichter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nordlicht)* in der Bedeutung eines Bewohners Norddeutschlands schon seit Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts, jedoch erlangte diese Bezeichnung erst mit der Verwendung durch den deutschen Politiker [Franz Josef Strauß](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Josef_Strau%C3%9F) weitere Verbreitung, der damit Parteifreunde aus den Bundesländern Schleswig-Holstein und Niedersachsen verspottete (Quellen: Pfeiffer: Das große Schimpfwörterbuch, Eichhorn-Verlag, [Openthesaurus.de](http://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/edit/12915)). Diese "Nordlichter" werden im Süden (vor allem in Bayern) dadurch auch von Bewohnern anderer nördlicher Bundesländer unterschieden, denn diese sind ja *["Preußen"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preu%C3%9Fen)*.

Eine ähnliche spöttische (aber gutgemeinte) Bezeichnung der Süddeutschen fehlt im (nord-)deutschen Sprachgebrauch. Man bezeichnet die Menschen meist nach dem Land oder der Region aus der sie stammen:

- Hessen - die Hessen
- Schwaben - die Schwaben
- Rheinland - die Rheinländer
- Baden - die Badener (oder in Württemberg abfällig *Badenser*)
- usw.

Comment: Der von dir verlinkte OpenThesaurus schreibt dazu, dass *Nordlicht* oft von Norddeutschen als beleidigend empfunden wird. Das kann ich nicht nachvollziehen; ich finde die Bezeichnung eigentlich ganz angenehm und kenne auch niemanden, der dadurch gekränkt würde. Die anderen dort genannten Synonyme sind dann schon eher beleidigend.

Comment: @OregonGhost: ich denke auch, dass die ursprüngliche Würze und der Spott dieser Bezeichnung inzwischen verloren gegangen ist.

Comment: @Oregon Sehe ich genauso. Nordlicht empfinde ich als eher positiv bis neutral, Muschelschubser oder Fischkopp würde ich jetzt nicht jemandem an den Kopf werfen wollen. Wobei sich eine Freundin aus HH hin und wieder selbst so bezeichnet, also ist das Empfinden da evtl. regional unterschiedlich?

Comment: @takrl: Das Empfinden ist im Zweifel persönlich unterschiedlich. Es gibt sicher Leute, die generell etwas kräftigere Ausdrücke im Alltag verwenden und dann auch über sich selbst so reden. Die Wörterbücher erwähnen Nordlicht übrigens alle als "scherzhaft für Norddeutsche" - ich bin aber gar nicht so sicher, dass es nicht eigentlich maximal umgangssprachlich ist.

Comment: "Licht" ist ja generell eher positiv, man assoziiert z.B. Intelligenz.

Comment: Baden-Württemberger sind summa summarum Schwaben. Um sich als Badenern zu bezeichnen muss man schon selbst ein Schwabe sein, in Berlin weiß man was gemeint ist: Kehrwoche plus Geiz. ;)

Answer (score 5):

How far south? Austrians are commonly referred to as "Oesis" or "Schluchtenscheisser".

Answer (score 2):

Als Wetterphänomen, welches mit Licht zu tun hat, und nur in Süddeutschland vorkommt - gemessen an Deutschland (in der Schweiz, Österreich, Frankreich u. Italien müßte es das auch geben) fällt mir 'Alpenglühen' ein, welches aber nicht benutzt wird, um die, die es tagtäglich sehen können, zu bezeichnen. `Alpenglüher` wäre aber auch geknittelt. Das Wetterphänomen 'Fön' ist m.W. auch nicht benutzt worden, um die `Jodeldeutschen` zu foppen. `Fönfühler` hätte m.E. auch keine Chancen rasch an Popularität zu gewinnen.

Da die Preußen die Toleranz erfunden haben ;) kennen Sie keine abfälligen Begriffe für Bayern und Baden-Würtis.

Für die Österreich gibt es immerhin `Alpenrepublik` als milde Form der Beschimpfung. Diese nennen uns `Piefkes`.

Comment: Alpenrepublik als milde Beschimpfung? Das hat als Beschimpfung mMn dieselbe Beißkraft wie "Europäisches Land". Oo

Comment: Das kann schon spöttisch benutzt werden, zumal große Teile Wiens und Oberösterreichs gar nicht in den Alpen liegen.

Answer (score 0):

Das Gegenteil von „Nord“ ist „Süd“ oder „Austral.“ Es gibt ein „Australlicht,“ glaube ich.

Comment: Es geht hier aber nicht um das Phänomen des Nordlichts, sondern um die Bezeichnung "Nordlichter" für Bewohner Norddeutschlands.

Comment: @HendrikVogt "Aurora australis" wäre doch eine sehr nette Bezeichnung für Süddeutsche und Österreicher.